# Why browser is showing different back slash for a email validation regex. How to prevent that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, unicode, utf-8

I am haivng this pattern in js file:

```
var emailPattern = /^[^\W_](\.{0,1}[^<>(){\}[\]\\.,;:%\s@\"]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;
```

While the page is loaded, I am getting this in view source,

```
var emailPattern = /^[^＼W_](＼.{0,1}[^<>(){＼}[＼]＼＼.,;:%＼s@＼"]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}＼.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;
```

(This page is a japanese specific page but js is in plain english).

Anyway to prevent \ (normal backslash ) from becoming this ＼ (unicode: `&#65340;`)

Comment: Does this happens in the entire file?

Comment: Yes.. I don't have any other backslashes .. so yes.

Comment: Which browser? What kind of HTTP server is serving the JS? Is there a test URL we can look at? What character encoding are you using to serve the page? We need a lot more details to help out here...

Comment: Chrome it is .. and it's internal so can't share any link but you can try this in chrome console. remove the var part and paste the first pattern in console and try emailPattern.test("abc@abc.com"); it will return true. then do the same for the second and it will return false.

Comment: A suggestion, check with a byte editor and see if the backslashes are ok in the js file. If it is so then the problem is how your server handles the js document

Comment: @Arindam: What Gabber said. It's obvious the second pattern won't work; it's not obvious why the server/browser/editor is botching your document. It looks like there's some kind of filter on the server/editor that "prettifies" things (maybe also turning straight " quotes into curly ones, etc.). But without knowing more about the server, there's no way to tell exactly what's going on.

Comment: @Gijs: I do agree with you. Let me see if I can provide more information.

Comment: Yes, I'd put my money on @Gijs being correct. And if it's not to "prettify", it could ironically to make javascript less likely to work (to block XSS attacks).

Comment: @ArindamPaul eh, so, you wrote below in a comment on Stefan's answer that you "do some encoding thing in perl". Can you put that perl up on a pastebin and link it? It sounds like that's the problem...

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a character encoding issue.

For example, when editing [Shift-JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) encoded files in SubEthaEdit, backslashes appear as `\` (0x5C) in the editor but are actually inserted as `＼` (0xFF3C) in the file.

Copying the source code from the editor converts it back to UTF-8 and gives me a "normal" backslash in the clipboard.

A workaround in SubEthaEdit would be to enter the `¥` character, which is 0x5C in Shift-JIS.

All this is specific to SubEthaEdit but maybe you're facing a similar problem.

Comment: This is gr8 info .. we are trying it out.

Comment: But as Stefan said, this is for SubEthaEdit. Not working in our case. The problem is to display the japanese character in browser, we do some encoding thing in perl. Now this regular expression is affected. IS there anyway to mention encoding style specifically for a regex.

Comment: Are you sure that your file is UTF-8 encoded and that the backslash is encoded as `0x5C`?

Comment: Yes the encoding in the page is UTF-8 for sure. The character which we are talking about is http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff3c/index.htm    normal backslash(keyboard one) is converted to this full width one (as described in the mentioned link).

Answer (score 0):

Think about your editor and browser policies:

- First line : Consolas 10
- Second line : MS Mincho 10

Comment: No it is not that .. font is same. everything same.. infact if you copy and search the character it is not a backslash at all.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your code string to notepad, then copy it back to your code from there. This will destroy your unicode characters and convert the backslashes to real backslashes.

Comment: But my source code is fine. I can check that against console. Only this pops up when rendering in browser.