# JS backslash escape char being converted to non-escaping character by Shift JIS

Tags: javascript, perl, utf-8, shift-jis

I'm currently working on a website that has two versions, one American website that's served as utf-8 and one Japanese version that's served as Shift JIS. The site is generated using Perl.

The problem:

I'm serving Javascript akin to the following.

```
var text = "test \"quote\"";
```

Which, on the Japanese site, is returning an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier." This is because the backslash is being converted to an elongated backslash character ＼, which isn't seen as an escape character and thus is breaking the line.

I can't seem to find anyone else running into this problem which makes me suspicious that there isn't something fundamentally wrong with our website. Has anyone encountered a similar situation and found a solution?

Many thanks

Comment: It's impossible to help you without your Perl code.

Comment: Well that line is raw JS as part of a Mason template that is embedded in a few thousand other lines of code.

Comment: You should at least show us the part of the code that does the encoding. If it is done by Mason, show us how you setup Mason to do it.

Comment: I don't have ownership or access to it, I realise that's not particularly helpful but the only part of it that's relevant is that its encoded in shift JIS. I'm going to update this with a hack that I found though. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

I found some helpful information here:

[Why browser is showing different back slash for a email validation regex. How to prevent that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107219/why-browser-is-showing-different-back-slash-for-a-email-validation-regex-how-to)

Which lead me to this upsetting hack:

```
var text = "test ¥"quote¥"";
```

This works perfectly. Now, obviously this isn't the way to do it, but it will enable other devs to get on testing other JS interactions on the site while I concentrate on refactoring this code into something that doesn't rely on character escaping. I hope this information helps someone else at some point!

Comment: I've run into the same thing, but in the reverse direction, "\" in the Shift_JIS encoded Simulink files is getting turned into "¥", most frequently with "\n" becoming "¥n" (that's a literal \n and not a new-line character, although if not for the "conversion" it would get interpreted by Simulink as such). This happens in my case using `iconv -f shift_jis -t utf8 <filename>`.